# UnknownException in Kafka SimpleConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using a modified version of the Kafka SimpleConsumer to expose offsets to a rest api, based on: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example

However, the behavior of the example is inconsistent with the shell command:
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker ...

In that sometimes it works, and sometimes it returns successfully with an embedded error. In other words, the check:

if (response.hasError()) {...}

is entirely useless because the response (as far as it's aware) has no error. But if I drop in a:

response.toString().contains("error")

then sure enough, there is an error in the response. The error is:

kafka.common.UnknownException

So it doesn't know that it has an error and, once the exception is pulled out, it's expressed in the form of an IDontKnowWhatWentWrongException. Add to that the fact that this happens intermittently to an arguably more complex object (ironically named "Simple"Consumer), and it smells fishy.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is this a known issue?

Will post solution here if I get a response from ASF. Thanks.

Comment: Kafka is undergoing lots of change. The offsets are more easily monitored via Jmx and, since hundreds of mBeans are created for even a small cluster having a few topics, a robust monitoring solution (Zabbix etc.) helps to track them. Quantifind also has a tool that deploys as a jar: https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor.

Comment: In my case: We have a few automated solutions for alerting and responding via feature toggles when things go off the rails - all built in Java. I am using Jmx for tracking errors, offsets, lag, etc. and the SimpleConsumer primarily for basic responsiveness (also exposing partition leaders and offsets via rest, but not depending on rest as the means of determining offsets).